# Proof by induction $2n!>n^2$ for all integer n greater or equal than 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-verification, induction

I need help with this exercise.

### What I have done so far is:

> $2n!>n^2$  for all integer n greater or equal than 3: *$n\geq 3$*

- When n=3:

$2*3!>3^2$

$2*1*2*3>9$

12>9 Which is correct

- Now it is time for the demonstration. When n=>n+1:

$2(n+1)!>(n+1)^2$

$2n!(n+1)>(n+1)^2$

Well, I can't go on, I don't know how to finish this proof. Could anyone help me with this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need induction.
\begin{align*}2n!
&=2n(n-1)(n-2)!
\\&\geq2n(n-1)
\\&=2n^2-2n
\\&=n^2+(n^2-2n)
\\&=n^2+n(n-2)
\\&>n^2\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Assume that for $n\geq 3$ we have $2n! > n^2$. We have to show that it holds for $n+1$ i.e. $2(n+1)! >(n+1)^2$.

Starting with the left-hand side:
$$
2(n+1)!=2(n+1)n! > (n+1) n^2 =n^3+n^2
$$
where the first inequality follows from the Induction Hypothesis. Now we only need to show that $n^3> 2n+1 \Leftrightarrow n^3-1 = (n-1)(n^2+n+1) > 2n$. But this holds since $n-1 > 1$, $n^2+n+1 > 3n +n+1 >2n$.

Answer (score 0):

$2\cdot(n+1)! = 2\cdot(n+1)\cdot n! > (n+1) (n)^2$ by the inductive hypothesis.

$(n+1)n^2 > n^3 > (n+1)^2$ when $n>2$